# How do I publish an Ivy Dependency via SBT?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

I am trying to use SFTP to publish a dependency to another server:

```
publishTo := Some(
  Resolver.sftp(name, host, "/home/user/.ivy2/local")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
)
```

This works as expected and it publishes to the remote server, but it doesn't create a "ivys" directory, only a "poms" directory. This leads Coursier (what I'm using on that machine to resolve dependencies) to be unable to resolve the dependency because it can't find "ivys/ivy.xml".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check out `publishLocal`, I used that today and it dropped my jar into the location you mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To publish Ivy style, as opposed to Maven, you should enable the following setting in your build:

```
publishMavenStyle := false
```

`Resolver.ivyStylePatterns` doesn't govern the publishing style (which artifacts to generate, etc.) It only specifies the repository paths structure, which are different between Ivy and Maven.